# ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.os.PersistableBundle" Otto Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, classnotfoundexception, otto

I have a strange issue.
I have an app which I deployed on an Android 4.4 device and use Otto library.
I deployed the app on an Android 5.0 device. It still works.
I retried on the 4.4 and the app won't launched.

Apparently, it tries to use PersistableBundle.class which a API 21 class.
Here my log :

```
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.os.PersistableBundle" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/fr.myapp.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/fr.myapp, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:656)
            at com.squareup.otto.AnnotatedHandlerFinder.loadAnnotatedMethods(AnnotatedHandlerFinder.java:52)
            at com.squareup.otto.AnnotatedHandlerFinder.findAllProducers(AnnotatedHandlerFinder.java:126)
            at com.squareup.otto.HandlerFinder$1.findAllProducers(HandlerFinder.java:33)
            at com.squareup.otto.Bus.register(Bus.java:191)
```

Comment: I am not sure if you are the one who commented on the issue, but there is [an outstanding issue on this](https://github.com/square/otto/issues/139).

Comment: Yep it's me. I just found the solution below.

Comment: updating android os to 5.0 solved the issue for me

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I find the "solution". 
Just remove this function from your activity :

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... while that probably works, that's really a workaround more than a "solution". Developers might want to use that method on the Android 5.0 and higher devices. Overriding a method that an older API level does not call normally is not a problem. Otto, as it is iterating over methods, should have exception handling in place to deal with this scenario, IMHO.

Comment: It's a Api 21 Method. So if you're under 21, your app crash because it can't be executed. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle)

Comment: Just use public void `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)`not ` onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState)`

Comment: Same error was happening to me with `onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)`. Changed the method to `onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and error was "resolved".

Answer (score 0):

Change **targetVersion** to the API version of the device you are running.

I had **targetVersion = 21** when my device had 4.4 (API 19), changing the value to 19 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem on Samsung Galaxy 3mini and Local operator phones.But i fixed with override activity method.i hope it works for you.

```
 @Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        BusApplication.getInstance().register(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on [FAG](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/faq/)

> Some Android versions seem to have a bug with reflection when calling getDeclaredMethods or getMethods

in this case `PersistableBundle` was added in API level 21 and when we use it in lifecycle methods like **onCreate** or **onSaveInstanceState** this error happens.

If you use of **any of** following methods in your code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState,PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
}

@Override
public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState,PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
}
```

Use following methods instead (or remove above methods if useless)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

In my case i use this method in baseActivity and made the crash

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState) 
}
```

Simply i replace this with

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```

And problem solved.