# Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My IDE is Android Studio 2.0. SDK is 23
This is my error log(there are so many same logs and I list only one):

> 05-10 22:19:21.430 1835-1835/edu.jazzy.testconsumer E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method edu.jazzy.testconsumer.MipcaActivityCapture.access$super

my build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "edu.jazzy.testconsumer"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile files('libs/zxing.jar')
}
```

And I don't know why there is always occur error after I google for hours.

Comment: Have you checked out this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857860/classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-android-os-persistablebundle-otto-an

Comment: @cristianorbs I have checked it, this question was the first when I google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this sort of message whenever there is code in your app that refers to classes/methods/fields that do not exist on the device. So long as you do not actually *execute* any lines that refer to those missing items, there is no problem.

Note that [the question linked to from the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28857860/115145) is for a case where there is an actual crash, in that case due to some unfortunate reflection from Otto. Your error message from your question is not a crash.

Comment: I got the error when I compiled APK, and the error occured again when I operate my app(click some button).

Comment: @Joe: Lots of things get logged with error severity in LogCat. Few are actual problems with your app, and most of those will be a crash with a full Java stack trace. *Other* than the message appearing in LogCat, what evidence do you have that you actually have a problem that is tied to this message?

Comment: I am tring to implement Scan QR code, and I import some libs, some apps import the libs occur the error and cannot run, and some apps have no error and alright when it run. So I think the error is the reason make my apps crash.

Comment: @Joe: If your app is crashing, you will have Java stack traces to examine. Focus on those.

Comment: Thx, you are right, I checked the log again, there were another error. I have fixed it now. Thx again