# org.roboguice.shaded.goole.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/os/PersistableBundle

Tags: java, android, roboguice

Hi i am gett the error below when i run my app on a kitKat device only

Any suggestion?

```
 org.roboguice.shaded.goole.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/os/PersistableBundle
                                                                                            at org.roboguice.shaded.goole.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2199)
                                                                                            at org.roboguice.shaded.goole.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3934)
                                                                                            at org.roboguice.shaded.goole.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3938)
                                                                                            at org.roboguice.shaded.goole.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4821)
                                                                                            at org.roboguice.shaded.goole.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4827)
                                                                                            at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:48)
                                                                                            at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.get(MembersInjectorStore.java:68)
                                                                                            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getMembersInjector(InjectorImpl.java:983)
                                                                                            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getMembersInjector(InjectorImpl.java:990)
                                                                                            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.injectMembers(InjectorImpl.java:976)
                                                                                            at roboguice.inject.ContextScopedRoboInjector.injectMembersWithoutViews(ContextScopedRoboInjector.java:247)
                                                                                            at roboguice.activity.RoboFragmentActivity.onCreate(RoboFragmentActivity.java:62)
                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
                                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/os/PersistableBundle
                                                                                            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Native Method)
                                                                                            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:656)
                                                                                            at com.google.inject.HierarchyTraversalFilter.getAllMethods(HierarchyTraversalFilter.java:56)
                                                                                            at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.computeInjectableMembers(InjectionPoint.java:749)
                                                                                            at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:686)
                                                                                            at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:371)
                                                                                            at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.createWithListeners(MembersInjectorStore.java:93)
                                                                                            at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.access$000(MembersInjectorStore.java:37)
                                                                                            at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:45)
                                                                                            at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:42)
                                                                                            at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(FailableCache.java:37)
                                                                                            at org.roboguice.shaded.goole.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3524)
                                                                                            at org.roboguice.shaded.goole.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2317)
                                                                                            at org.roboguice.shaded.goole.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2280)
                                                                                            at org.roboguice.shaded.goole.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2195)
                                                                                            at org.roboguice.shaded.goole.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3934) 
                                                                                            at org.roboguice.shaded.goole.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3938) 
                                                                                            at org.roboguice.shaded.goole.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4821) 
                                                                                            at org.roboguice.shaded.goole.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4827) 
                                                                                            at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:48) 
                                                                                            at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.get(MembersInjectorStore.java:68) 
                                                                                            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getMembersInjector(InjectorImpl.java:983) 
                                                                                            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getMembersInjector(InjectorImpl.java:990) 
                                                                                            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.injectMembers(InjectorImpl.java:976) 
                                                                                            at roboguice.inject.ContextScopedRoboInjector.injectMembersWithoutViews(ContextScopedRoboInjector.java:247) 
                                                                                            at roboguice.activity.RoboFragmentActivity.onCreate(RoboFragmentActivity.java:62) 
                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451) 
                                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.os.PersistableBundle" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.jr.wallet.app-1.apk", zip file "/data/data/com.jr.wallet.app/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.jr.wallet.hce-1.apk.classes2.zip"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.jr.wallet.app-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                                            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
                                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Class
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857860/classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-android-os-persistablebundle-otto-an

Answer (score 0):

Google advice not to use RoboGuice, use Dagger2 instead - it work at compile time

Answer (score 0):

It can be fixed by adding

`<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />`

line to mainfest

```
<Application
 <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
/>
```